C++ template: access members from source template struct
I want to create following class template:

Holds a list of objects of different classes derived from same base class.
These objects are all of the same size (derived classes are same size)
Being able to do some computation on all members from a function.
Has a member to access each object of the list individually.
List and members can be created at compilation, no need for dynamic lists.
User interface must be simple, since it will be used many times and by different programmers on the teams, with little c++ experience.
Use C++14 standard, gcc compiler.

Example of user code. This is what I want to keep as simple as possible:
//list of sensors with a member for each sensor
typedef struct {
    cOneSensor_f A4_temp1 = cOneSensor_f ("A4t1", 0x1234 /*, x, y, ... and some more configuration data*/);
    cOneSensor_i B4_speed = cOneSensor_i ("B4s0", 0x2001 /*, x, y, ... and some more configuration data*/);
}Sensor_list_4_s;

//put the list inside a class template to be able to control all of them as a whole,
//but also access each sensor individually
cSensorsList<Sensor_list_4_s> Sensor_list_4( 4 );

//get sensor values
void do_sensors_stuff()
{
    //all sensors as a whole
    Sensor_list_4.update();

    //access each sensor individually
    float A4t1 = Sensor_list_4.A4_temp1();
    int   B4s0 = Sensor_list_4.B4_speed();
}

Behind the scene It can be as complicated as needed. It could be somehting like this:

A base class for objects
Some derived classes for different objects variations (I can manage all derived classes from base)
Template class to hold the list of objects.

class cOneSensor {}
class cOneSensor_f: class cOneSensor {}
class cOneSensor_i: class cOneSensor {}

template <typename T>
class cSensorsList: public T
{
private:
    int bus_code;
    cOneSensor *p_to_sensors_array;
    int nSensors;

public:
    cSensorsList(int bus_code):bus_code(bus_code)
    {
        //---  here is what I don't know how to do: get sensor list from typename T
        nSensors = 0; //getSensorListSize_from_T(/* T */);
        p_to_sensors_array= 0;//getSensorListPointer_from_T<T>(/* T */);
        // ---
    }
    void update(void) {
        for (int i=0; i<nSensors; i++)
            p_to_sensors_array[i].update();
    }
};

With this code I get:

✅ Members on cSensorsList to access each object individually.
✅ Symple to user perspective.
✅ All objects in a class.

But I don't know how to:

❌ Within the class cSensorsList, get the list of members of template struct, to loop through all objects in the list to so some actions: pointer_to_sensors_array = getSensorListPointer_from_T().


isn't it a std::tuple you're asking for?

As a side note about editing the post: I don't know why code doesn't get highlighted for c++. I used "```lang-cxx" for code

simpler: ```cpp

@Oersted, It could be std::tuple, but I don't get to make it work with it, nor a good guide on how to do it. (by the way, that was fast response!)

a minimal example: https://godbolt.org/z/fW9qzceE5

A side note: in general use std::vector (or std::array for fixed size) instead of raw C arrays (cOneSensor *sensors_array) that requires manual memory management.

You can use std::tuple but you would have access to one item only by index and not by name (such as Sensor_list_4.A4_temp1()).

We need access by name: Sensor_list_4.A4_temp1(). It's actually one of the main points of this. This is an important part of the code. Otherway, we have to maintain  a correlation of indexes and sensors, using an enum for example. We want to avoid it at all cost.

I still wonder if we could use std::tuple on any way in the constructor to populate the sensors_array with all the members from Sensor_list_4_s.

Have you considered using dynamic polymorphism ? If you do so, you could maintain a map (string->cOneSensor) and access one item with the name, something like Sensor_list_4["A4_temp1"]. And the update method would be trivial.

@edrezen, with polymorphism The compiler won't geerate error if we use the wrong sensor name: Sensor_list_4["A3_temp1"] for example, or will it?. Also, this is much slower access than Sensor_list_4.A3_temp1 or Sensor_list_4[enum_A3_temp1], isn't it?

You can use the method at that will throw an exception if the key doesn't exist. Sure it will take some time compared to a more static solution but if you don't access to an item zillions times, the overhead should not be that bad. So you could write something like Sensor_list_4.at("A3_temp1"). Note also that the complexity of std::map::at should be logarithmic in the size of the container.

Since base class is an struct, not a class, the this pointer points to first inherited member from template. There is not vtable.
Also, given all derived cOneSensor_X classes are the same size, we can calculate the number of members on base template struct T.
template <typename T>
class cSensorsList: public T
{
//...
public:
    cSensorsList(int bus_code):bus_code(bus_code)
    {
        nSensors = sizeof(T)/sizeof(cOneSensor);
        p_sensors_array = (cOneSensor*)this; // <<--- pointer to first inherited member
    }
    void update(void) {/*...*/}
};

Note: If derived cOneSensor_X classes are not the same size, you can try a more sophisticated algoritm and sequencially capturing initial position of each member.
But I'm pretty sure (or I wish) there should be a more elegant solution.

I selected this answer because the other two change sustancially the user API. This solution posted here doesn't require to change the user API posted on the question

If you want to use dynamic polymorphism (ie. with virtual mechanism), you can have something like the following.
It simply holds a std::map that links a string with an instance of a subclass of cOneSensor. Note that you initialize an instance of cSensorsList with instances of sensors allocated on the fly, so cSensorsList has the ownership of these instances and has to delete them in its destructor.
Using dynamic polymorphism this way makes cSensorsList::update very easy to write.
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct cOneSensor 
{
    virtual void update() = 0; 
};

struct cOneSensor_f:  cOneSensor 
{
    void update () override { std::cout << "updating cOneSensor_f\n"; } 
};

struct cOneSensor_i:  cOneSensor 
{
    void update () override { std::cout << "updating cOneSensor_i\n"; }
};

class cSensorsList 
{
private:
    std::map<std::string,cOneSensor*> map_;
public:

    using value_type = typename decltype(map_)::value_type;

    template<std::size_t N>
    cSensorsList (value_type const (& arr)[N])
    {
        // we fill the map with the provided array
        for (value_type const& entry : arr) 
        {
            map_[entry.first] = entry.second;
        }
    }
    
    ~cSensorsList() 
    {
        // cSensorsList is responsible for object deallocation.
        for (auto& entry : map_)  { delete entry.second; }
    }
    
    decltype(auto) at (std::string const& key)  { return map_.at (key); }

    void update(void) 
    {
        for (auto entry : map_)  { entry.second->update(); }
    }
};

int main()
{
    cSensorsList sl = {{
      { "A4_temp1", new cOneSensor_f{}},
      { "B4_speed", new cOneSensor_i{}}
    }};
    
    sl.update();
    
    try
    {
        auto& a = sl.at("A4_temp1");    // this one is ok 
        auto& b = sl.at("whynot");      // this one will throw an exception
    }
    catch(const std::out_of_range& e)
    {
        std::cout << "exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}

Demo

I think that rather than using a raw pointer with new and delete you should instead be using std::unique_ptr<>> so that the allocated memory lifetime can be managed more safely.

The following source code works with my simple test harness. I think that it provides the same interface that you are requesting. See the main() at the bottom of the source listing.
I used Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 to work with this. My C++ skills are a bit rusty so there are probably changes that would make this a bit less messy.
I expect that using std::variant from C++17 might be more appropriate than the union I'm using but like I said, my C++ skills are a bit rusty.
I've enjoyed playing with this so thank you.
#include <iostream>

// following union is used to store the value of the sensor as a kind of variant or any.
// 
class SensorBase {
public:
    enum class SensorValueType { Unknown = 0, FloatVal = 1, IntVal = 2 };
    struct SensorValue {
        enum class SensorValueType  valType;
        size_t    sensorId;
        union {
            float valFloat;
            int   valInt;
        };
        operator float() { return valFloat; }
        operator double() { return valFloat; }
        operator int() { return valInt; }
        operator long() { return valInt; }
    };

protected:
    SensorValue  val;

public:
    SensorValue initFloat = { SensorValueType::FloatVal, 0, 0.0 }; // SensorValue(0.0);
    SensorValue initInt = { SensorValueType::IntVal, 0, 0 }; // SensorValue(0);
    SensorBase(const SensorValue& y) { val = y; }
    SensorBase(size_t id, double valF) {
        val.valType = SensorValueType::FloatVal; val.sensorId = id;
        val.valFloat = valF;
    }
    SensorBase(size_t id, int valI) {
        val.valType = SensorValueType::IntVal; val.sensorId = id;
        val.valInt = valI;
    }
    ~SensorBase() {}

    virtual int UpdateVal(void) = 0;    // we require that derived classes provide this method.

};

class SensorObj : public SensorBase
{
public:
    SensorObj(const SensorValue& y) : SensorBase(y) { }
    SensorObj(size_t id, double valF) : SensorBase(id, valF) {}
    SensorObj(size_t id, int valI) : SensorBase(id, valI) {}
    ~SensorObj() {}

    virtual int UpdateVal(void) { return 0; }    // we allow this to be over ridden by the final class
};

//--------------------------------------------------------
// The various kinds of sensor types follow.
// these classes encapsulate a particular sensor type by extending
// the templated class to allow the use of these classes to be
// similar in use of methods.
//
// the concept is to allow the compiler to figure out things as much as possible.
class SensorFloat : public SensorObj {
public:
    SensorFloat() : SensorObj(initFloat) {}
    SensorFloat(SensorValue const y) : SensorObj(y) {  }
    SensorFloat(size_t id, float x) : SensorObj(id, x) { val.sensorId = id;  val.valFloat = x; }
    SensorFloat(size_t id, double x) : SensorObj(initFloat) { val.sensorId = id;  val.valFloat = x; }
    ~SensorFloat() {}

    float myValue() { return val.valFloat; }
    virtual int UpdateVal(void) {
        val.valFloat = val.valFloat + 2.5f;
        return 0;
    }

    operator float() { return val.valFloat; }

};

class SensorInt : public SensorObj {
public:
    SensorInt() : SensorObj(initInt) {}
    SensorInt(SensorValue const& y) : SensorObj(y) {}
    SensorInt(size_t id, int x) : SensorObj(id, x) { val.sensorId = id;  val.valInt = x; }
    ~SensorInt() {}

    int myValue() { return val.valInt; }
    virtual int UpdateVal(void) {
        val.valInt = val.valInt + 3;
        return 0;
    }

    operator int() { return val.valInt; }
};



// list of the sensors in a struct. each sensor has an identifier and an initial value.
// when the list is updated, those values will change depending on the type of sensor.
// this is just source to show the concept. actual sensors will need something more
// appropriate in the update logic.
    struct {
        SensorFloat Sensor_101;
        SensorInt   Sensor_102;
        SensorInt   Bogus;         // used to indicate the end of the list for the end() function.
        // provide the opportunity to use range operator
        SensorObj* begin() { return (SensorObj *)&SensorList; }
        SensorObj* end() { return (SensorObj*)&SensorList.Bogus; }
        // update all the sensors in the list in this struct
        void update(void) {
            // uses the begin() and end() methods for range
            for (auto& x : SensorList) {
                x.UpdateVal();
            }
        }
    } SensorList = { SensorFloat(101, 3.4), SensorInt(102, 6) };

    // standalone update function to update the list of sensors. this builds an array of the objects then processes it.
    void updateSensors(void)
    {
        SensorObj* ar[] = { &SensorList.Sensor_101 , &SensorList.Sensor_102 };

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0]); i++) {
            ar[i]->UpdateVal();
        }
    }

int main(void)
{
        auto a1 = SensorList.Sensor_101.myValue();
        auto a2 = SensorList.Sensor_102.myValue();

        std::cout << "a1 = " << a1 << " and a2 = " << a2 << std::endl;

        SensorList.Sensor_101.UpdateVal();
        SensorList.Sensor_102.UpdateVal();
        
        a1 = SensorList.Sensor_101.myValue();
        a2 = SensorList.Sensor_102.myValue();

        std::cout << "a1 = " << a1 << " and a2 = " << a2 << std::endl;

        std::cout << "\n Update vec" << std::endl;

        updateSensors();

        a1 = SensorList.Sensor_101.myValue();
        a2 = SensorList.Sensor_102.myValue();

        std::cout << "a1 = " << a1 << " and a2 = " << a2 << std::endl;

        std::cout << "\n Update vec" << std::endl;

        SensorList.update();

        a1 = SensorList.Sensor_101.myValue();
        a2 = SensorList.Sensor_102.myValue();

        std::cout << "a1 = " << a1 << " and a2 = " << a2 << std::endl;
        return 0;
}

The output of the above is as follows:
Hello World!
a1 = 3.4 and a2 = 6
a1 = 5.9 and a2 = 9

 Update vec
a1 = 8.4 and a2 = 12

 Update vec
a1 = 10.9 and a2 = 15

C:\Users\rcham\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe (process 400) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .


Regular classes and some utility functions using std::tuple might be what you want:
struct Sensor_list_4_s{
    cOneSensor_f A4_temp1;
    cOneSensor_i B4_speed;

    auto as_tuple() const { return std::tie(A4_temp1, B4_speed); }
    auto as_tuple() { return std::tie(A4_temp1, B4_speed); }
};

template <typename... Ts>
void update(std::tuple<Ts&...> t)
{
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L // C++17
    std::apply([](auto&... sensors){ (sensors.update(), ...); }, t);
#else
    std::apply([](auto&... sensors){
        std::initializer_list<int> ini{(sensors.update(), 0)...};
        static_cast<void>(ini); // Avoid warning for unused variable
        ();
    }, t);
#endif
}

template <typename F, typename... Ts>
void apply_for_each(F f, std::tuple<Ts&...> t)
{
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L // C++17
    std::apply([](auto&... sensors){ (f(sensors), ...); }, t);
#else
    std::apply([](auto&... sensors){
        std::initializer_list<int> ini{f(sensors), 0)...};
        static_cast<void>(ini); // Avoid warning for unused variable
        ();
    }, t);
#endif
}

template <typename... Ts>
void update2(std::tuple<Ts&...> t)
{
    apply_for_each([](auto& sensor){ sensor.update(); }, t);
}

template <typename T>
void update3(T& t)
{
    apply_for_each([](auto& sensor){ sensor.update(); }, t.as_tuple());
}

so then
Sensor_list_4_s list /* = ... */;

update(list.as_tuple());
apply_for_each([](auto& sensor){ sensor.update(); }, list.as_tuple());
update2(list.as_tuple());
update3(list);


Thanks @Jarod42. However, My compiler complains about apply: error: 'apply' is not a member of 'std'. The value of __cplusplus = 201402L

Indeed std::apply is C++17, but can be rewritten for c++14
